# How can i integrate jsf 1.2 with tiles?

Tags: jsf, tiles

How can i integrate jsf 1.2 with tiles?

Comment: Tiles? Go for Facelets: https://facelets.dev.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/Tiles_and_JSF
http://www.jsftutorials.net/tiles/jsf-tiles.html

But [Facelets](https://facelets.dev.java.net/) is more JSF-oriented templating solution.